# How do I distribute Contents from Column A to Column B, C, and D evenly in Excel

Tags: excel

Let's say I have a list of numbers

Column A
1
2
3
4
5
6
7

and I want to move these numbers to B, C, D.  evenly like

Column B: 1,2,3, Column C: 4,5, Column D: 6,7

The list of numbers always changes.

Comment: can I do it with VBA?

Comment: Are these numbers in only the first row or distributed in rows?

Comment: They are distributed in rows.

Comment: Are you fine with the distribution as column B: 1,2, column c: 3,4 and Column D: 5,6,7?

Comment: that is ok too as long as it's not 3,3,1 or 1,3,3. or 6,1,0

Comment: Will post the macro.. getting problems in editting and posting.. give me a min..

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
```

'

`k = 0
r = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
For i = 1 To r
    j = 2
    If k = 0 Then
    k = 1
    End If
    If i <= (r / 3) Then
        Cells(k, j).Value = Cells(i, 1)
        k = k + 1
        If (i + 1) > (r / 3) Then
        k = 0
        End If
    End If
    j = 3
    If i > r / 3 And i <= 2 * (r / 3) Then
        Cells(k, j).Value = Cells(i, 1)
        k = k + 1
        If (i + 1) > 2 * (r / 3) Then
        k = 0
        End If
    End If
    j = 4
    If i > 2 * (r / 3) Then
        Cells(k, j).Value = Cells(i, 1)
        k = k + 1
    End If
Next i
End Sub`

Comment: received an error on  If i > r / 3 And i  2 * (r / 3) Then

Comment: Done with all the edits. Try out the macro and let me know if it serves the purpose.

Comment: The loop is only from 1 to last filled row of column A. Try with small column  A size first.

Comment: Upvote or mark it as correct if the answer is right. Might help someone in the future. Let me know if there are any problems with the code.